# RuntimeError( RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am learning basic flask but cannot import db(database) from freecodecamp
I cannot find the solution plz answer this query as soon as possible
There are 4 files :
when I write from app import db the pythonshell shows error

app.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL'] = 'sqlite://test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

main.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/main.css')}}">
      
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
<h1>Template</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

[Terminal Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHPAf.png)

Comment: You have a typo in your configuration code. It is `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` not `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize `db` as well,

```
db = SQLAlchemy() # db intitialized here
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite://test.db"
db.init_app(app)
```

It's `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` not `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL`